# How to sort a 2d Vector

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector

I have a vector L containing vectors with 2 doubles each. I want to sort the vectors in L by their first element.

```
vector<vector<double>> L;
```

I tried to use the std::sort algorithm with a self-written compare function as follows:

```
    bool compare(const vector<double> &v1, const vector<double> &v2)
    {
        return v1[0] < v2[0];
    }

    void out_2d_vecotr_as_value_pairs(vector<vector<double>> &L)
    {
        L = sort(L.begin(), L.end(), compare);
            ...
    }
```

But I get this error I don't understand for the line calling the sort() function:

```
projet.cc:234:38: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::vector<std::vector<double> >’ and ‘void’)
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: *Where* do you get the error? And is it really the full and complete output as well, there no other notes or output from the compiler?

Comment: Note that if your vectors have many columns, sorting rows will have a large performance hit.  Better to sort a vector of indices that point to the rows in the 2D array instead of sorting the 2D array itself.

Comment: When using *any* function, like [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort), always look up its documentation, so you know how it works. Doing so would have quickly told you that `std::sort` doesn't return anything - it sorts the container *in place*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) doesnt return anything. The vector is sorted in place.

Replace

```
L = sort(L.begin(), L.end(), compare);
```

by

```
sort(L.begin(), L.end(), compare);
```

Comment: Thanks, I only looked for my error in the arguments :(